# New-ComplianceSearchAction -Purge 10 Items Limit

Tags: powershell

We created a compliance search with 35 results, and when I create a new compliance search action it is limited to 10 results (documented by MSFT). I have read that you can rerun the compliance search action multiple times, but I always get 10 results, and it never seems to decrement to 0 confirming full deletion of the content. What am I missing here?

```
`New-ComplianceSearchAction  -SearchName $searchName -Purge -PurgeType HardDelete -Confirm:$FALSE -Force`
```

Tried rerunning the New-ComplianceSearchAction, but results always 10, despite how many times I run it.

Tried creating new compliance searches, in hopes of getting "batches" of 10, and the results are always the same 10 of 35.

Comment: I've tried deleting the SearchAction and recreating it in a loop, and I still get the same 10 results